# RegEx for Period and Space

Tags: regex, vb.net

I want to write a regex to verify inputs. The inputs have the following format:

```
N. Crystal

O. J. Faucon

A. V. E. David
```

`"^[A-Z. ]*+([a-zA-Z])*$"` is not working. How can I match the above examples?

Comment: @KonradRudolph I think your edit fixes the problem (the missing asterisk after the second `[a-zA-Z]` :)

Comment: Try Konrad's fix (i.e. adding the asterisk).

Comment: vb.net says: parsing "^[A-Z. ]*+([a-zA-Z])*$" - Nested quantifier +.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I didn’t add any asterisk, I just put backticks around the regular expression.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Oh, that explains the *italics* in the OP :)

Answer (score 3):

.NET rightly complains about the nested quantifiers. `*` and `+` are redundant, remove one.

```
^[A-Z. ]*([a-zA-Z])*$
```

Furthermore, using `*` here seems rather unintuitive, unless you really want to accept empty input. In reality, aren’t you expecting *at least one* of the characters? (We can also remove the redundant parentheses since the grouping makes no sense.)

```
^[A-Z. ]+[a-zA-Z]+$
```

Finally, this accepts just about everything, e.g. “BAR...   FOOxyz”. You might want to be more precise:

```
^([A-Z]\. )+[a-zA-Z]+$
```

Now the first group explicitly matches an initial (i.e. a capital letter followed by a dot and a space), and it matches multiple of those, but at least one.

Comment: Thank you :D | but with you ^[A-Z. ]+[a-zA-Z]+$ , typing: .A. s is working, but in my case. The 1st character must be capital followed by a dot and a space. the only format which must be allowed is:
N. Crystal or O. J. Faucon or A. V. E. David